# How to solve inhomogeneous Laguerre equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the technique to solve this equation?

$$xy''+(1-x)y'+\frac{y}{2}=e^{-x}$$

I tried solutions of the type: $y=Ae^{-x}+Bxe^{-x}$, but not all the terms cancelled.

Would I have to use the Wronskian?

Comment: Have you heard of Frobenius' method?

Comment: @BennettGardiner Yes, but I though it would be possible to solve it without a series solution.

Comment: I think the homogenous case is a classic example for the Frobenius method. Not sure about the non-homogeneity. Sometimes you can recognise a series solution as the expansion of some closed form expression. If you knew one solution, you could find the other via variation of parameters, however I'm afraid even the homogeneous solution isn't very nice - http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%27%27%2B%281-x%29y%27%2By%2F2%3D0

Answer (score 2):

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides of the equation I get the first order linear ODE:

$$-2sY(s) - s^2Y'(s) + sY(s) + sY'(s) + Y(s) + \frac{Y(s)}{2}= \frac{1}{s + 1 } $$

Which has particular solution (according to WA):

$$\frac{\sqrt{-(s-1)s}}{\sqrt{1-s}s^{\frac{3}{2}}} - \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}s}{\sqrt{-(s-1)s}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-s}s^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}s}{\sqrt{-(s-1)s}}\right)}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-s}\sqrt{s}}$$

So if a closed form exists for the particular solution it will be the inverse Laplace transform of this and is unlikely to be anything nice...

Comment: And what about initial conditions?

Comment: @Dmoreno For this particular ODE, if I have done my math correctly, when taking the Laplace transform all terms involving initial conditions cancel.

Comment: Then, I can't see how this is independent of the initial conditions. This really bothers me! haha.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the Laguerre differential equation has not a simple closed form for $\lambda \neq 0$. In your case $\lambda = 1/2$. The solution of the **homogeneous** Laguerre equation,

$$L[y] = y'' + (1-x) y' + \lambda y =0, $$ is given in terms of special functions:

$$y(x) = \alpha_1 U(-\lambda, 1,x)  + \alpha_2 L_\lambda(x),$$ where $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind and $L_\lambda$ is the generalized Laguerre polynomial. The non-homogenous part can be obtained with the help of the method of variation of parameters.

You can obtain a series expansion of every part of the solution by using the Frobenius method as @Bennet Gardiner pointed out in his comment.

Hope this helps!

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $xy''+(1-x)y'+\dfrac{y}{2}=0$ :

Let $y=\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds$ ,

Then $x(\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds)''+(1-x)(\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds)'+\dfrac{1}{2}\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$x\int_Cs^2e^{xs}K(s)~ds+(1-x)\int_Cse^{xs}K(s)~ds+\dfrac{1}{2}\int_Ce^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$x\int_C(s^2-s)e^{xs}K(s)~ds+\int_C\left(s+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_Cs(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)~d(xs)+\int_C\left(s+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$\int_Cs(s-1)K(s)~d(e^{xs})+\int_C\left(s+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$[s(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)]_s-\int_Ce^{xs}~d((s^2-s)K(s))+\int_C\left(s+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$[s(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)]_s-\int_Ce^{xs}((s^2-s)K'(s)+(2s-1)K(s))~ds+\int_C\left(s+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)e^{xs}K(s)~ds=0$

$[s(s-1)e^{xs}K(s)]_s-\int_Ce^{xs}\left(s(s-1)K'(s)+\left(s-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)K(s)\right)~ds=0$

$\therefore s(s-1)K'(s)+\left(s-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)K(s)=0$

$s(s-1)K'(s)=-\left(s-\dfrac{3}{2}\right)K(s)$

$\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}=-\dfrac{2s-3}{2s(s-1)}$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}ds=-\int\dfrac{2s-3}{2s(s-1)}ds$

$\int\dfrac{K'(s)}{K(s)}ds=\int\left(\dfrac{1}{2(s-1)}-\dfrac{3}{2s}\right)ds$

$\ln K(s)=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(s-1)-\dfrac{3}{2}\ln s+c_1$

$K(s)=cs^{-\frac{3}{2}}(s-1)^\frac{1}{2}$

$\therefore y=\int_Ccs^{-\frac{3}{2}}(s-1)^\frac{1}{2}e^{xs}~ds$

But since the above procedure in fact suitable for any complex number $s$ ,

$\therefore y_n=\int_{a_n}^{b_n}c_n(k_nt)^{-\frac{3}{2}}(k_nt-1)^\frac{1}{2}e^{xk_nt}~d(k_nt)=k_n^{-\frac{1}{2}}c_n\int_{a_n}^{b_n}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}(k_nt-1)^\frac{1}{2}e^{k_nxt}~dt$

For some $x$-independent real number choices of $a_n$ and $b_n$ and $x$-independent complex number choices of $k_n$ such that:

$\lim\limits_{t\to a_n}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}(k_nt-1)^\frac{3}{2}e^{k_nxt}=\lim\limits_{t\to b_n}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}(k_nt-1)^\frac{3}{2}e^{k_nxt}$

$\int_{a_n}^{b_n}t^{-\frac{3}{2}}(k_nt-1)^\frac{1}{2}e^{k_nxt}~dt$ converges

For $n=1$ , the best choice is $a_1=1$ , $b_1=\infty$ , $k_1=1$ when $\text{Re}(x)\leq0$

$\therefore y_1=C_1\int_1^\infty t^{-\frac{3}{2}}(t-1)^\frac{1}{2}e^{xt}~dt$ when $\text{Re}(x)\leq0$